# Getting "encountered array-valued parameter binding" When Checking To See If A Parameter Is NULL

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, filter, null, jpql

I'm trying to write a query for a filter using Spring Boot and JPQL. Not all parameters are required and some can be null. I have several parameters and have no problem checking if most of them are null or not but I am having trouble with one of them only. Basically, `reviews` is an array of double[] and I want to check if it's null or not. If it's not null, it can have several reviews e.g. (1,2,3). The review column itself is a double. Here's my code

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM Restaurant r WHERE " +
            "(:name IS NULL " + 
            "OR r.name LIKE CONCAT('%',:name, '%')) " +  
            "AND (:city IS NULL " +
            "OR r.city = :city) " + 
            "AND ((:reviews) IS NULL " +
            "OR r.review IN (:reviews)) ")
            
    
    Page<Restaurant> filter(Pageable Page, String name, String city, double[] reviews);
```

Here's my error:

```
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Encountered array-valued parameter binding, but was expecting [java.lang.Double (n/a)]
```